# Turning multi-line string into single comma-separated list in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this format:

```
host1,app1
host1,app2
host1,app3
host2,app4
host2,app5
host2,app6
host3,app1
host4... and so on.
```

I need it like this format:

```
host1;app1,app2,app3
host2;app4,app5,app6
```

I have tired this: `awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 }' data | sed 's/,$/\n/'`
 and it gives me this:

`app1,app2,app3` without the host in front.

I do not want to show duplicates.

I do not want this:

```
host1;app1,app1,app1,app1...
host2;app1,app1,app1,app1...
```

I want this format:

```
host1;app1,app2,app3
host2;app2,app3,app4
host3;app2;app3
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show what you've tried so far and how it failed, as currently it's just a requirements dump and looks like you want somebody else to do all the work for you.

Comment: I can't imagine why this got closed. It's got sample input, expected output, a statement of the problem, and an attempted solution. What more could anyone want in a question?

Comment: @EdMorton most close votes and downvotes were thrown before the attempted solution was edited in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With input sorted on the first column (as in your example ; otherwise just pipe it to `sort`), you can use the following `awk` command :

```
awk -F, 'NR == 1 { currentHost=$1; currentApps=$2 } 
         NR > 1 && currentHost == $1 { currentApps=currentApps "," $2 }
         NR > 1 && currentHost != $1 { print currentHost ";" currentApps; currentHost=$1; currentApps=$2 }
         END { print currentHost ";" currentApps }'
```

It has the advantage over other solutions posted as of this edit to avoid holding the whole data in memory. This comes at the cost of needing the input to be sorted (which is what would need to put lots of data in memory if the input wasn't sorted already).

Explanation :

- the first line initializes the `currentHost` and `currentApps` variables to the values of the first line of the input
- the second line handles a line with the same host as the previous one : the app mentionned in the line is appended to the `currentApps` variable
- the third line handles a line with a different host than the previous one : the infos for the previous host are printed, then we reinitialize the variables to the value of the current line of input
- the last line prints the infos of the current host when we have reached the end of the input

It probably can be refined (so much redundancy !), but I'll leave that to someone more experienced with `awk`.

[See it in action !](https://ideone.com/WXlyqS)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=","; ORS="" }
    $1!=prev { print ors $1; prev=$1; ors=RS; OFS=";" }
    { print OFS $2; OFS=FS }
    END { print ors }
' file
host1;app1,app2,app3
host2;app4,app5,app6
host3;app1
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: You are wrong. As I've requested of you previously, please don't comment on posts you do not understand as it just clutters up the site with irrelevant nonsense.

Comment: Oh it's you again.  Some people will never learn.  Is there I way I can just filter you out when reviewing Very Low Quality questions?

Comment: Just don't post comments about code you don't understand and then you'll have successfully filtered out me and everyone else you're bothering. If you have something informed and useful to say then of course you should say it but rubber-stamping a tools "possibly low quality" flag when you have no idea if the answer is actually low quality or not since you don't know the domain is a complete waste of your time and everyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
declare -A hosts
while IFS=, read host app
do
    [ -z "${hosts["$host"]}" ] && hosts["$host"]="$host;"
    hosts["$host"]+=$app,
done < testfile

printf "%s\n" "${hosts[@]%,}" | sort
```

The script reads the sample data from `testfile` and outputs to `stdout`.

Comment: You have a bug - missing the `-r` from the read. More importantly though that would be orders of magnitude slower than an equivalent awk script. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk script:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]",":"")$2}END{for(i in a) printf "%s;%s\n",i,a[i]}' file
```

The script creates entries in the array `a` for each unique element in the first column. It appends to that array entry all element from the second column.

When the file is parsed, the content of the array is printed.