# AWK: Robust way of using inline if-then-else

Tags: awk

I often use inline if-then-else statement `(...?...:...)` when concatenating fields of an input file together with a separator (comma, colon, semicolon...).

The typical use case is to build a string with fields of the input file and store this string in an array, like this:

```
$ cat file
a 1
b 2
a 3
c 1
b 26
c 4
c 2
```

In order to transpose such a file, I use this awk script:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?",":"")$2}END{for(i in a) printf "%s:%s\n",i,a[i]}' file
```

[I was told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287080/turning-multi-line-string-into-single-comma-separated-list-in-bash/51287913?noredirect=1#comment89555709_51287913) that this way of using inline if-then-else isn't robust enough, and I should use this way:

```
awk '{a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]",":"")$2}END{for(i in a) printf "%s:%s\n",i,a[i]}' file
```

Obviously for this simple input file, the result of both script is the same.

So why would the second script be more "robust"?

I'm actually looking for an input example that would make fail the first script but not the other.

Comment: FYI `inline if-then-else statement` = `a ternary expression`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I guess you put a one more `a[$1]=` in your first awk one-liner. It should be:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?",":"")$2}....
```

I think your question is concerning why checking `$1 in a` is better than checking `a[$1]`. The both one-liners will work for your input. Because the string concatenation made `a[$1]` become string. For string, if it is not empty, awk will evaluate it into `true`. also for string `"0"`

However if somehow you have to handle your input as numbers to fit the required output, then the two boolean checking can be different. If a number is `0`, awk will evaluate is as `false`.

Have a look at this example:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{if(0)print "number"; if("0")print "string"}'
string
```

You see that only the later one was printed.

Therefore the `$1 in a` is better, because it will always work no matter the `a[$1]` stores a number or string.

However you can use `if(a[$1])` check, if you set the `a[$1]` in your code, and you 100% sure that the `boolean a[$1]` will give what you expected. E.g.you made string concatenation `""$2` in your codes. Or you set something like `a[$1]=1`

In general `$1 in a` is better.

Comment: Another thing is that `if(a[$1])` will actually add an entry to the `a` array with index `$1`, whereas `$1 in a` will not. In some cases this could be a memory concern or even possibly affect the logic of the program.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Kent mentioned, consider that in general fields can be null strings. The [original question I commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51287080/1745001) that prompted your current question had CSV input so let's use that again now just for better visibility than space-separated:

```
$ cat file
a,1
b,
a,3
c,
b,26
c,4
c,2

$ awk -F',' '{a[$1]=a[$1](a[$1]?",":"")$2}END{for(i in a) printf "%s:%s\n",i,a[i]}' file
a:1,3
b:26
c:4,2

$ awk -F',' '{a[$1]=($1 in a?a[$1]",":"")$2}END{for(i in a) printf "%s:%s\n",i,a[i]}' file
a:1,3
b:,26
c:,4,2
```